# ¿Estoy definiendo mal mi variable en SpringBoot?

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring, backend, thymeleaf

Tengo este código y estoy trabajando con Spring Boot y thymeleaf

```
@GetMapping("/transaction/diagrama-flujo/{idSolicitud}")
public String transaction (@PathVariable("idSolicitud") Long idSolicitud, Model model) {
    SOLICITUD_ENTITY diagrama = I_SOLICITUD.findById(idSolicitud).get();
     model.addAttribute("diagrama", diagrama);
```

Y obtengo un error en el findByID que dice lo siguiente: The method findById(Long) is undefined for the type I_SOLICITUD

Y sé que es porque I_SOLICITUD es una clase que tengo ahí, más no una variable del repositorio.. pero en realidad estaba recreando el código de ésta página https://stackabuse.com/thymeleaf-path-variables-with-spring-boot/ y en ese ejemplo, la variable del repositorio tampoco está definida en ningún lado.. pueden entrar al enlace para ver que de verdad no lo definen en ningún lado... podrían orientarme sobre qué hacer?
Con "variable de repositorio" me refiero a **postRepository**

```
@GetMapping("/viewPost/{postId}")
public String viewPost(@PathVariable("postId") Long postId, Model model) {
Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).get();
model.addAttribute("post", post);
return "view-post";
```

Answer (score 0):

En Spring boot hay métodos predefinidos que se extienden de CrudRepository y/ó JpaRepository (repo.findById(id), repo.findByAll(), otros).
Entonces deberías tener una capa de @Repository extrayendo la interfaz genérica.

```
@Repository
public interface SolicitudRepository extends CrudRepository<Solicitud, Long> {}
```

En tu controller (aunque debería ser en el service) inyectas tu respository.

```
@Autowired SolicitudRepository I_SOLICITUD;
```

Y ahí le indicas tu método:

```
@GetMapping("/transaction/diagrama-flujo/{idSolicitud}")
public String transaction (@PathVariable("idSolicitud") Long idSolicitud, Model model) {
    SOLICITUD_ENTITY diagrama = I_SOLICITUD.findById(idSolicitud).get();
     model.addAttribute("diagrama", diagrama);
```

[Puedes leer más sobre @Repository acá](https://gustavopeiretti.com/spring-boot-componente-repository/)